# Google Play private app closed testing with user outside of my organisation

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have a managed app for a specific organisation.

I would like to setup the closed testing for some users in the organisation as well as some that are outside of my organisation.

I added the emails in the tester list and released a new version.

Only the users from my organisation can see and install the app in the store after enrolling for the beta program.

Is it possible to let the users outside the organisation access the app on the play store ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed testing can be done through Managing Gmail Group. App accessibility can be given by adding members to the group. Only the members will see the app avialabilty in Playstore